# How to show md-progress-circular centered on top of all content

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I would like to use `md-progress-bar` while data is loaded from the server.

While `md-progress-bar` is shown, I would like all other content not to be clickable. Also, the progress animation should be shown in the window's center.

I tried using the following HTML in my template:

```
<md-dialog style="background-color:transparent;box-shadow:none">
    <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" aria-label="wait">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ></md-progress-circular>
    </div>
</md-dialog>
```

But it flickers and shows scroll bars:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Can you create a Plunker to demonstrate? I've no idea about the flicker, but you can eliminate the scroll bar with css `overflow-y: hidden`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have found the solution by now, but if not, this is the reason: the spinning circle is an SVG element and then transformed (for spinning effect) as on this image.

[image: spinner issue]

That transormation make internal content height a bit heigher than size of the spinner itself and hence you can see that scroll bar.

Adding height (in your case `70px` should be fine, but that value depends on the spinner size; adding extra height won't harm either as you hide your `md-dialog` background) to the div with `layout="row"` should fix it.

```
<md-dialog style="background-color:transparent;box-shadow:none">
    <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="center center" aria-label="wait" 
         style="height:70px;">
    <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" ></md-progress-circular>
    </div>
</md-dialog>
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: Such an easy solution in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-ng-app='demo' ng-controller='demoController'>
    <md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
       <!––some code here-->
    </md-tabs>  
    <div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-align="space-around" style="position: absolute;bottom:1%;height:2000px;width:100%">
       <md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate" md-diameter="100" style="position:fixed;bottom:50%" ></md-progress-circular>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code worked for me. Could be accommodated to your code.